# jQuery Form Validation Plugin: Requiring e-mails to be .EDU addresses

Tags: jquery, ajax, email, forms, validation

I'm trying to build a sign-up form that will only accept .EDU e-mail addresses.
I also want to keep the AJAX functionality I have (using the "remote" parameter)
to ensure that the e-mail address hasn't been used before.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
$.validator.addMethod("edu-email", 
    function(value) {
        return (value.endsWith(".edu"));
    },
    "e-mail address must end in .edu."
);
```

JavaScript doesn't have a string.endsWith. You'll have to add your own.

Now add "edu-email" to the form input class.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - figured it out!

Just had to use `jQuery.validator.addMethod` to create a function to check the substring
of the last 3 letters, leaving my other code intact, and add a class referring to the
added method in my HTML.