# Implement .edu email addresses only during registration process

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Can anyone please give me a detailed answer as to how to only allow .edu email addresses to signup during the registration process. I have looked into this:

[jQuery Form Validation Plugin: Requiring e-mails to be .EDU addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620311/jquery-form-validation-plugin-requiring-e-mails-to-be-edu-addresses)

but i still need further clarification.

Thaks

Comment: You'd need to do the same validation server-side, as well.  If you only do your validation client side, it's pretty trivial for people to evade it.

Answer (score 8):

This will need to be done server-side (as well as whatever you are doing to notify the user on the client-side).

Use a regular expression like

```
if (preg_match('/@.*\.edu$/', $email)) {
```